# Finding argmax of an integral -- can I take logarithm of one of the terms?

Tags: integration, optimization, logarithms

Suppose I need to solve for the **argmax** of $x$ for an integral that can be factored as follows:

$$
A = \mathrm{argmax}_x \int_Y f(x,y)g(y)dy
$$

Where both $f()$ and $g()$ are strictly positive, and the form of $f(x,y)$ is sufficiently horrible that I can't solve the integral directly. However, what **is** easy to solve is this **different** integral

$$
\int_Y \log{\left[f(x,y)\right]}g(y)dy
$$

Since $x$ only appears in the $f()$ function, and the integrand is factored like so, it seems to me that the argmax of the second integral is equal to the argmax of the first integral, because the logarithm is continuous and strictly increasing. So, am I allowed to do:

$$
A = \mathrm{argmax}_x \int_Y \log{\left[f(x,y)\right]}g(y)dy
$$

?

I think I can, but I want to double check to see if there are any subtleties to this.

(If it helps to give stronger conditions / motivate what I'm trying to do: $f()$ and $g()$ are both probability density functions, and I need to marginalize over $y$ and get the MLE for $x$. Assume that the functions are continuous and otherwise obey enough regularity conditions for all of this to make sense).

Comment: No you cannot, just like you cannot take the logarithm of terms of a sum.

Comment: I know that it changes the value of the integral, but I don't care about the value of the integral. All I care about is whether the operation preserves the argmax of $x$, and I can't see why it doesn't.

Comment: you can take the logarithm of a sum and keep the same maximizer but you cannot take the logarithm of the individual terms (which is essentially what you are doing with the integral).